# sql запрос с приоритетом

Tags: php, mysql

как создать sql запрос так, чтоб, например, первые 12 товаров (из 24) выводились по условию top = 1 и затем все остальные товары?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY top DESC;`

Comment: *первые 12 товаров (из 24)* Товаров всего 24, или надо выбрать 12 из тех, где `top = 1`, и остальные 12 из тех, что `top != 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если товаров много, а надо по 12 из каждой группы, то

```
    (
    SELECT select_fieldset 
    FROM table 
    WHERE top = 1 
    ORDER BY order_by_fieldset_1 LIMIT 12
    )
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT select_fieldset
    FROM table 
    WHERE top != 1 
    ORDER BY order_by_fieldset_2 LIMIT 12
    )
ORDER BY (top != 1), order_by_fieldset_0
```